# Matching data attributes between records of different layers

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I'd like to know how I can match data attributes between records of different layers, in which there are the same fields, in one shot.
[image]

[image]

[image]

For example, i'd like to transfer data from "test_1" to "test_2" quickly, especially when there are lots of fields. Any suggestion?

Comment: How many rows are there in each layers?

Comment: about 500 records....so an automatic solution is needed.

Comment: Without providing more information (best: provide sample data) it will be difficult to give advice. Based on what criteria you want to connect the lines? How does QGIS know which line 1 belongs to which line 2? Do they have a common attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information you provided: use this expression in field calculator:

```
attribute (
    get_feature_by_id (
        'test_1', 
        1
    ), 
    'FIELD2'
)
```

If you have several lines in each layer, replace `1` with the name of your feature id field to correctly assign the line form layer 1 to the corresponding feature on layer 2.

[image]

Include more information in your question to get a more detailed answer: how/based on what criteria you want to join the two lines?

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!! I have 2 layers with about 500 records (they have the same number of records) and the fields are the same. They are spaced with no geometric criteria, so i cannot use "join attributes by position".

Comment: So does it work or you're asking for more advice? Sorry, not quite clear for me....

Comment: Yes, sorry. It works, but with the expression (attribute..) it sets 'B' in the FIELD2 for all the records. It shouldn't set specifically based on feature id?

Comment: In the above expression, replace `1` with the name of your feature id field

Comment: Perfect, it works! Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

If each layer has one feature, you can use this script in QGIS Python Editor:

```py
L = lambda name: QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(name)[0]

layer1 = L("test_1")
layer2 = L("test_2")

feat1 = layer1.getFeature(0)
feat2 = layer2.getFeature(0)

with edit(layer2):
    for field in layer1.fields().names():
        idx = layer2.fields().indexOf(field)
        layer2.changeAttributeValue(0, idx, feat1[field])
```

In your case, if both layers have multiple features, the layers have to include a corresponding field with unique-value.